# Error:(54, 91) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Tags: android, json, string, int

I'm trying to connect my app with server but getting an error. Please help!

I'm trying to connect my app using volley library to the server,but whenever I try to run my code I get the following error

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

I tried changing from String to int, but it didn't help!

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,          **<-------------error here**
                            showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray student = response.getJSONArray("student");
                                for (int i=0;i<student.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject students = student.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String firstname = students.getString("firstname");
                                    String lastname = students.getString("lastname");
                                    String age = students.getString("age");

                                    result.append(firstname+""+lastname+""+age+""+"\n");
                                }
                                result.append("==\n");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your conversion? int is that age??

Comment: i tried doing this
int age = students.getInt("age");

but it didn't help!

Comment: @AnujGajbhiye Can you share your `JSON` response ?

Comment: @Anuj Gajbhiye what i was asking where you error points at ? and you can avoid that by working with a suggestion that i mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got your problem now.

You're using incorrect method of `JsonObjectRequest` from `Volley`.

You're calling this method

`JsonObjectRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)`

instead of

`JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)`

where first argument is an `int`.

You're passing in 4 arguments, so the upper method is being called where your `int method` is being converted to `String url`

You can fix it by passing 5 arguments, and all should be good then.

Comment: i tried doing this `int age = students.getInt("age");` but it didn't help!

Comment: @AnujGajbhiye Please share your `JSON` response. It might clear the confusion

Comment: this is all the code of my application..rest is initialization and xml file.

Comment: @AnujGajbhiye I found the problem and suggested an answer

Comment: @AnujGajbhiye Please mark answer if it fixed your issue. Thanks

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo nice didnt noticed that +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

// follow this

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
                        "url", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

          
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```